# difference between ros-kinetic-desktop install and bare-bone version?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to list out the packages that would be installed during desktop installation (ros-kinetic-desktop) and ros-base installation (ros-kinetic-ros-base) without actually installing them. This is to check what exactly are the differences in ros base version and the desktop version. Is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255482/difference-between-ros-kinetic-desktop-install-and-bare-bone-version?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All metapackages for all variants are documented in [REP 142: ROS Indigo and Newer Metapackages](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html).

If you'd also like to know all *system dependencies* that will be installed (and you're using `apt-get`), then (from `man apt-get`):

```
APT-GET(8)

       apt-get - APT package handling utility -- command-line interface

...

  -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
      No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Simulate.
```

so running any `apt-get install` command with the `-s` switch will only simulate what would happen, and should let you inspect what particular set of packages will be installed without actually installing them. One-liner: `sudo apt-get install -s $some_pkg | grep Inst | awk '{ print $2 }'`.

You might also just select `n` when asked by `apt-get install` whether you want to continue (which it asks before installing anything).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0